# How to connect remote mysql database in Ubuntu using Mono and XSP

Tags: c#, mysql, ubuntu, mono

first, I install mono, xsp server, mysql-server, mysql-client in Ubunut. In my C# code, I use the following connection.

```
const string constr = "Server=localhost;" +
          "Database=test;" +
          "User ID=root;" +
          "Password=root;" +
          "Pooling=false";
```

Then, I publish the project in Windows visual studio C# project. Then copy these files to Ubuntu `/home/sea/web_host`   I also import the database to Ubuntu, and make the database as localhost.

In Ubuntu, I run

```
sea@virtual-machine:~/web_host$ xsp --port 8125
xsp4
Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
Root directory: /home/sea/web_host
Listening on port: 8125 (non-secure)
Hit Return to stop the server.
```

In my browser, I can see the webpage using `localhost:8125/index.aspx`
However, the web cannot connect to the database. I have already imported the data into MySQL database in Ubuntu and I can view them in the Ubuntu MySQL workbench. But the web cannot access MySQL database.

What is the problem?

Comment: how do you know it cannot connect? I'm guessing you're seeing an error message? then include the error message in the question

Comment: @knocte Any thoughts for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34987706/2404470)

Comment: I asked questions, without the answers I cannot help

Comment: @knocte I gave up this problem and found another solution which was not related to this problem.  Sorry I do not have the error message now.