# How to find existence of .Net Framework Data Provider for MySql on Mono Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, ubuntu, mono

After [solving basic porting issues](http://xameeramir.github.io/solving-mysql-mono-port-issues/), I was trying to connect to MySql database from ASP.NET Mono project.

Whenever, I try to connect to the database, the following error is thrown (please run the snippet):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body { background-color: #FFFFFF; font-size: .75em; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; color: #696969; }
a:link { color: #000000; text-decoration: underline; }
a:visited { color: #000000; }
a:hover { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; }
a:active { color: #12eb87; }
p, ul { margin-bottom: 20px; line-height: 1.6em; }
pre { font-size: 1.2em; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 0px; }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-size: 1.6em; color: #000; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
h1 { font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; }
h2 { font-size: 1em; padding: 0 0 0px 0; color: #696969; font-weight: normal; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 20px; }
h2.exceptionMessage { white-space: pre; }
h3 { font-size: 1.2em; }
h4 { font-size: 1.1em; }
h5, h6 { font-size: 1em; }
#header { position: relative; margin-bottom: 0px; color: #000; padding: 0; background-color: #5c87b2; height: 38px; padding-left: 10px; }
#header h1 { font-weight: bold; padding: 5px 0; margin: 0; color: #fff; border: none; line-height: 2em; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 32px !important; }
#header-image { float: left; padding: 3px; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 1px; }
#header-text { color: #fff; font-size: 1.4em; line-height: 38px; font-weight: bold; }
#main { padding: 20px 20px 15px 20px; background-color: #fff; _height: 1px; }
#footer { color: #999; padding: 5px 0; text-align: left; line-height: normal; margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px; font-size: .9em; border-top: solid 1px #5C87B2; }
#footer-powered-by { float: right; }
.details { font-family: monospace; border: solid 1px #e8eef4; white-space: pre; font-size: 1.2em; overflow: auto; padding: 6px; margin-top: 6px; background-color: #eeeeff; color: 555555 }
.details-wrapped { white-space: normal }
.details-header { margin-top: 1.5em }
.details-header a { font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none }
p { margin-bottom: 0.3em; margin-top: 0.1em }
.sourceErrorLine { color: #770000; font-weight: bold; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var hideElementsById = new Array ();
 window.onload = function () {
  if (!hideElementsById || hideElementsById.length < 1)
   return;
  for (index in hideElementsById)
   toggle (hideElementsById [index]);
 }
 
 function toggle (divId)
 {
  var e = document.getElementById (divId);
  if (!e)
   return;
  var h = document.getElementById (divId + "Hint");
  if (e.style.display == "block" || e.style.display == "") {
   e.style.display = "none";
   if (h)
    h.innerHTML = " (click to show)";
  } else {
   e.style.display = "block";
   if (h)
    h.innerHTML = " (click to hide)";
  }
 }
</script>
<title>Error 500</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
<div id="header">
<div id="header-text">Application Exception</div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <h1>System.ArgumentException</h1>
  <h2 class="exceptionMessage">Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.</h2>
  <p><strong>Description:</strong> HTTP 500.Error processing request.</p><p><strong>Details:</strong> Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Data.</p>
<div><strong>Exception stack trace:</strong></div>
<div class="details">  at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory (System.String providerInvariantName) [0x00036] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService (System.Type type, System.Object key, System.Func`3 handleFailedLookup) [0x0003b] in &lt;filename unknown&gt;:0 </div><div id="footer">
  <div style="color:Black;"><strong>Version Information:</strong> <tt>4.2.1 (Stable 4.2.1.102/6dd2d0d Thu Nov 12 09:52:44 UTC 2015)</tt>; ASP.NET Version: <tt>4.0.30319.17020</tt></div>
  <div id="footer-powered-by">Powered by <a href="http://mono-project.com/">Mono</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<!--
[System.ArgumentException]: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name &#39;MySql.Data.MySqlClient&#39; is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.<GetService>b__0 (System.ArgumentException e, System.String n) [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService (System.Type type, System.Object key, System.Func`3 handleFailedLookup) [0x00045] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService (System.Type type, System.Object key) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver+<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0 (System.Tuple`2 k) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (System.Collections.Concurrent.TKey key, System.Func`2 valueFactory) [0x00037] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService (System.Type type, System.Object key) [0x00032] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain+<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0 (IDbDependencyResolver r) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x0004d] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate) [0x00048] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService (System.Type type, System.Object key) [0x0002d] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService (System.Type type, System.Object key) [0x00022] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain+<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0 (IDbDependencyResolver r) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x0004d] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 predicate) [0x00048] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService (System.Type type, System.Object key) [0x0002d] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2[TFirst,TSecond].GetService (System.Type type, System.Object key) [0x00021] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T] (IDbDependencyResolver resolver, System.Object key) [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateConnectionFromProviderName (System.String providerInvariantName) [0x00005] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting (System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) [0x0003b] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig (System.String name, System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig config) [0x0000b] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize () [0x0005b] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create (System.Data.Entity.DbContext context) [0x0002b] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext () [0x0009b] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType (System.Type entityType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[TEntity].Initialize () [0x0000e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[TEntity].get_InternalContext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[TResult].System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider () [0x00016] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource] (IQueryable`1 source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0001f] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync[TSource] (IQueryable`1 source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1 predicate) [0x0001f] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6+<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c[TUser,TRole,TKey,TUserLogin,TUserRole,TUserClaim].MoveNext () [0x000d9] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.TaskExtensions+CultureAwaiter`1[T].GetResult () [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`2+<PasswordSignInAsync>d__29[TUser,TKey].MoveNext () [0x000ad] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at UI.Controllers.AccountController+<Login>c__async4.MoveNext () [0x00123] in /home/xameeramir/Projects/UI/UI/Controllers/AccountController.cs:337 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00007] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000d] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36 (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`1[TResult].CallEndDelegate (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () [0x00029] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) [0x00007] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d () [0x00014] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+AsyncInvocationWithFilters+<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f () [0x00002] in <filename unknown>:0 

[System.ArgumentException]: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
  at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory (System.String providerInvariantName) [0x00036] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService (System.Type type, System.Object key, System.Func`3 handleFailedLookup) [0x0003b] in <filename unknown>:0 
-->
```

Excerpt from `web.config`:

```
<entityFramework>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
</providers>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" >
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

- How do I figure out that the requested `.Net Framework Data Provider` is indeed installed?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a reference to the `MySqlClient` dll?

Comment: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/2be4298631 (that link is for SQLite but it applies to all ADO.NET providers) You have to configure the `<system.data>` part as well, or how can Mono load the provider?

Comment: As a warning, do not use comments to ask others to answer your question. These were being flagged across the site, and I have removed all the ones I found.

Comment: @BradLarson Oops, My intention was purely to get attention for the questions. What do you recommend other than comments? Btw, what are you using comments for as in this case? Lolz Also, thanks for your efforts in cleaning SO :)

Comment: @student - If people want to answer your question, they'll find their way to it. Comments are to be used for clarifications about questions or answers, or to provide supplemental information. I only used a comment for this because I didn't want to send a direct moderator message, which leaves a permanent record on your account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all providers, using this code (taken https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12kxkt25(v=vs.80).aspx). In my environment provider with invariant name MySql.Data.MySqlClient" was not listed

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable table = DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses();

            // Display each row and column value.
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",column.ColumnName,  row[column]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll check this and get back